"Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist"
Trying to create an NFT collection using metaplex and have been getting stuck with this error while trying to interact with the program using a nextjs client.
Here is the repo https://github.com/rtwhite10/token_2022_nft
I have seen that this error is usually related to testnet not having metaplex programs available but im testing using devnet so im a little confused.
Wondering if it has something to do with the program call here?
I have two programs that are very similar mint-nft which uses token-2022 and also mint-nft-standard which does not. Both are returning the same error. I created the standard as I was thinking it could be related to my token 2022 implementation in both theses programs  mint_nft.rs & create_collection.rs
full error
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"error": {
    "code": -32002,
    "message": "Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist",
    "data": {
        "accounts": null,
        "err": "ProgramAccountNotFound",
        "innerInstructions": null,
        "logs": [],
        "replacementBlockhash": null,
        "returnData": null,
        "unitsConsumed": 0
    }
},
"id": "a00cf2f3-e149-4f25-b632-61a2604bdfe6"

}
Thanks!

I figured it out, this was because my program was not deployed correctly. I somehow deployed it previously but the address was not the same as the one found in the IDL for the program. Re-deployed and now the error is gone. But I have a new error... hahaha
